# How to disable xmlns propagation to children

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I want to detach some `XmlElement` from one `XmlDocument` in order to insert it into another. But when I do this, descendant nodes with namespaces automatically get `xmlns` attribute appended. By some reason the target xml file fails to pass custom validation with all children namespaces set. Is there an option to supress `xmlns` propagation to descendants?

The following code illustrates the issue - the execution result is `<MakesMeSick:three xmlns:MakesMeSick="http://tempuri.org" />`

```
using System.Xml;

class Program
{
    static string xml = @"
<mydoc>
    <one xmlns:MakesMeSick=""http://tempuri.org"">
        <two>
            <MakesMeSick:three />
        </two>
    </one>
</mydoc>
";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
        XmlNode n = doc.SelectSingleNode("/mydoc/one/two");
        System.Console.WriteLine(n.InnerXml);
    }
}
```

Comment: What should be the result? `<three />`?

Comment: That's not a well-formed XML document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an element of the form `<prefix:localname>` then you **must** have an `xmlns:prefix="whatever"` somewhere in that element or an ancestor that explains what URI `prefix` maps to. It just doesn't make sense to have a prefix with no associated URI.

So, in your example, the output `<MakesMeSick:three xmlns:MakesMeSick="http://tempuri.org" />` is correct. If the `xmlns` was missing then it would not be a valid XML document.

Answer (score 0):

Your intent is not to just copy the elemnt, your intent is to transform it: the namespace is part of the element name in XML just like in C# or in Java. So you have to apply some hand-coding using XPath and focus on the [local name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.localname.aspx), or for more involved stuff maybe even resort to XSLT.